Goal Attainment With Exact Goals
I am working on a goal attainment problem with a goal of the following form:

produce exactly 80 units of the machine

I am trying to put the goal into this format for the fgoalattain function in Matlab:

Since this is an exact goal, would I need to add two constraints:
x - weight * gamma <= 80
-x - weight * gamma <= 80
Or is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
